# how to use cudpp without cmake?

Tags: cuda, cmake, cudpp

I need to use the scan function from cudpp. However, cudpp requires cmake to compile. Is there a way to use the scan function from cudpp into C code for CUDA directly? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have three possibilities:

- write your own version of scan function,
- try to copy code from cudpp and try to integrate with your project,
- compile cudpp with Cmake and use this library,
- your can use also thrust library ([homepage](http://thrust.github.com/)).